# How can I implement a annotation like @Deprecated to warning coders this is a dangerous method

Tags: java, annotations, ide

How can I implement an annotation(let's say @Dangerous) like @Deprecated to warning coders this is a dangerous method, use it carefully when calling.
And the best result is the IDE has some different UI to prompt coders like @Deprecated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is to write a runtime annotation to scan all @dangerous methods and print the warning log. Then write an IDE plugin to coloring dangerous method

Comment: Since the question is about compile-time checking, run-time scanning is not an appropriate answer.  A better answer would be to write an annotation processor, which works at compile  time.

Comment: yes, compile annotation is better, I wrote it wrongly